# Need to create a score using multiple variables (percentages) to show efficiency

Tags: percentages

We currently have 4 metrics that we are using to ascertain how efficient an employee is.

- ACD: Higher % is better
- CP: Lower % is better
- SYP: Lower % is better
- SP: Lower % is better

Is there a formula I can use to spit out a number that will be representative of a good or bad performance across those 4 metrics?

Comment: You can average the last three with $100$ minus the first one, and look for a low score. You might also want to consider a weighted average if some categories are more important than others. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean

Comment: Hi Ethan, great thank you. Worked perfectly

Comment: Posted my comment as an answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered. You can accept it. You could wait to see if there's a better one before you do.

Answer (score 0):

You can average the last three with $100$ minus the first one, and look for a low score. You might also want to consider a weighted average if some categories are more important than others. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean